# Using a variable to contain the name of another variable in order to call it

Tags: perl, xslt, xslt-1.0

Ok, so that title is a little confusing.  I think it's a little easier to just explain my problem out.  In perl, I am getting an array of string values (I'm not sure how long it will be because it depends on the file).  Because I don't know how long the array will be, I'm using a `for-each` in perl and creating a variable in perl that's just a long string that creates a bunch of variables in xslt.  For example, here's my code for doing that:

```
foreach my $node (@objects) {
    $count++;
    $xslt_vars = $xslt_vars . '<xsl:variable name="namedsets' . $count . '"/><xsl:text>' . $node . '</xsl:text></xsl:variable>';
}
```

My problem is I'm creating an unknown number of variables in my xslt stylesheet.  I have that number in a variable in xslt and I use it in a template like so:

```
<xsl:template name="expression">
    <xsl:param name="count"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$count &gt; $name-count">
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:for-each select=".//expression">
                <xsl:variable name="expression" select="."/>
                <xsl:variable name="express-test">
                    <xsl:text>$name-sets{$count}</xsl:text>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="trying">
                    <xsl:value-of select="{$express-test}"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:if test="contains($expression, $trying)">
                    <a>This Worked</a>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:call-template name="expression">
                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

So `$count` is not the same count as it is in the sample of perl code.  The perl `count` is `$name-count` (I don't know why I did this, but that doesn't really matter).  I created `$express-test` in order to have the name of the current `$namedset00` variable.  My problem is calling that variable with the correct number.  As you can see I tried setting `$trying` to the value of `{$express-test}`, but this syntax isn't allowed in xslt.  Has anyone done anything similar in xslt?  Or know how to call a changing variable name in xslt?

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do with your current approach is to do something like this:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="document('')//xsl:variable[@name = $express-text]" />
```

But I would suggest exploring how to use XSL parameters properly and pass in a single nodeset to your XSLT rather than patching the variables together with string concatenation. A nodeset will be much easier to access dynamically.